# Extjs - autocomplete filter 2 properties

Tags: autocomplete, filter, extjs4.1

By following this example http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/forum-search.html

I could apply the auto-complete feature on my combo box, using php/postgresql query retrieves the names then:

```
{
xtype: 'combo',
store: ds,
hideTrigger:true,
typeAhead: false,
id: 'search_input_text',
width: 187,
queryMode: 'remote',
hideLabel: true,
queryParam: 'query',
displayField: 'first_name',
valueField: 'first_name',

listConfig: {
 loadingText: 'Loading...',              
 getInnerTpl: function() {

    return  '{first_name}';  
                }}
 listeners: {
    buffer: 50,
    change: function() {
      var store = this.store;
      store.clearFilter();
      store.filter({
          property: 'first_name',
          anyMatch: true,
          value   : this.getValue()
      });

    }
  }
}
```

Now, I need to edit this to let user enter either the first or last name of the student, and then each name entered (first or last) will be shown in the combo box.

So, I edited the query to make it retrieve the names :

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM students WHERE first_name ILIKE '%$query%' OR last_name ILIKE '%$query%' ";
```

and:

```
displayField: 'first_name'+'last_name',
valueField: 'first_name'+'last_name',
```

---

```
return  '{first_name}'+'{last_name}';
```

---

```
store.filter({
              property: 'first_name',
              anyMatch: true,
              value   : this.getValue()
          },
{
              property: 'last_name',
              anyMatch: true,
              value   : this.getValue()
          }
```

but still, it retrieves only first names according to what user types, 
Note that if I use this alone:

```
store.filter({
                  property: 'last_name',
                  anyMatch: true,
                  value   : this.getValue()
              });
```

it works fine with last names only.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple filters to data store like this:

```
var filters = [
  new Ext.util.Filter({
  filterFn: function(item){return item.get('first_name') == this.getValue() || item.get('last_name') == this.getValue();
    }
  })
];

store.filter(filters);
```

The above code block is just an idea on how to apply multiple filters in the same field. Notice the double-pipe "||". You can use "&&" as per your needs. It is like SQL query.